# Jittery movement when using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having a problem with a jumping movement with using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. It seems to work fine until I get to the top of quadrants 1 and 2. Below is the code I am using and youtube link that shows what happens. Any insight would be really appreciated.

My goal is to rotate a UIWebView with an svg inside. Since I can't easily detect touch on the UIWebView alone, I'm putting a blank UIImageView over it. This allows me to detect the touch and prevent the copy dialog from popping up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_OmS0MPdEE&feature=youtu.be

```
    - (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects]; 
CGPoint location = [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view];
if(selected == 1) {
    CGFloat rads = atan2f(location.y - (grid1.frame.size.height/2),location.x - (grid1.frame.size.width/2));
    grid1.transform = grid1Btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rads);
}

    }

    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects]; 
CGPoint location = [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view];

if(CGRectContainsPoint(grid1Btn.frame, location))
{
    selected = 1;
}
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        selected = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use some `frame.size.*` in your computations. Note, that those values (unlike `bounds.size.*`) are affected by `transform`. Use `grid1.center` instead. It is also more logical (you rotate around center).

The next thing you need to fix is that it should not jump to new position when touches start :)

Comment: Prefect, such a simple solution. Thanks a lot!
I stopped it from jumping in the beginning by removing the transform in touchesBegan.

Answer (score 0):

The jerkiness is caused by the inherent inaccuracy of touch event locations.
Touch events that are located sufficiently close to the center of the frame have a high likelihood of straying to the diagonally opposite quadrant of the frame whilst a circle is being traced about the center of the frame.
This will result in a sudden jump of 90 degrees as observed in your video.
One way to avoid the problem is to introduce a dead zone about the center of the frame. Any touch that is located within a given radius of the center of the frame would not trigger the rotation to be recalculated.

Hope this helps.